# How to convert string into timezone aware date

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

Hello I have a string `2020-08-19 13:04:53`. I know that this time is in `Sydney, Australia` time. However, I need to convert this time into `New York, America` time as a date object. How can I do this?

```
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Sydney");
$time = '2020-08-19 13:04:53';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like

```php
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2020-08-19 13:04:53', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Output: 2020-08-19 13:04:53

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Output: 2020-08-18 23:04:53
```